# Most efficient way to determine if a string length != 0?

Tags: c#, string, content-length

I'm trying to speed up the following:

```
string s; //--> s is never null

if (s.Length != 0)
{
   <do something>
}
```

Problem is, it appears the .Length actually counts the characters in the string, and this is way more work than I need.  Anybody have an idea on how to speed this up?

Or, is there a way to determine if s[0] exists, w/out checking the rest of the string?

Comment: The perf problem you face is very likely solved somewhere else! Did you profile and find that the bottleneck is really here?

Comment: Out of curiosity what version of the framework are you targeting?

Comment: **NOTE** for other would-be-answerers: Eric's posted an answer that clarifies his question (kinda) below....

Answer (score 24):

EDIT: Now that you've provided some more context:

- Trying to reproduce this, I failed to find a bottleneck in `string.Length` at all. The only way of making it faster was to comment out both the test *and the body of the if block* - which isn't really fair. Just commenting out the condition slowed things down, i.e. unconditionally copying the reference was slower than checking the condition.
- As has been pointed out, using the overload of `string.Split` which removes empty entries for you is the real killer optimization.
- You can go further, by avoiding creating a new char array with just a space in every time. You're always going to pass the same thing effectively, so why not take advantage of that?
- Empty arrays are effectively immutable. You can optimize the null/empty case by always returning the same thing.

The optimized code becomes:

```
private static readonly char[] Delimiters = " ".ToCharArray();
private static readonly string[] EmptyArray = new string[0];

public static string[] SplitOnMultiSpaces(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return EmptyArray;
    }

    return text.Split(Delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

---

`String.Length` absolutely does *not* count the letters in the string. The value is stored as a field - although I seem to remember that the top bit of that field is used to remember whether or not all characters are ASCII (or used to be, anyway) to enable other optimisations. So the property access may need to do a bitmask, but it'll still be O(1) and I'd expect the JIT to inline it, too. (It's implemented as an `extern`, but hopefully that wouldn't affect the JIT in this case - I suspect it's a common enough operation to potentially have special support.)

If you already know that the string isn't null, then your existing test of

```
if (s.Length != 0)
```

is the best way to go if you're looking for raw performance IMO. Personally in most cases I'd write:

```
if (s != "")
```

to make it clearer that we're not so much interested in the length as a value as whether or not this is the empty string. That will be slightly slower than the length test, but I believe it's clearer. As ever, I'd go for the clearest code until you have benchmark/profiling data to indicate that this really *is* a bottleneck. I know your question is explicitly about finding the most efficient test, but I thought I'd mention this anyway. Do you have evidence that this *is* a bottleneck?

EDIT: Just to give clearer reasons for my suggestion of *not* using `string.IsNullOrEmpty`:  a call to that method suggests to me that the caller is explicitly trying to deal with the case where the variable is null, otherwise they wouldn't have mentioned it. If at this point of the code it counts as a bug if the variable *is* null, then you shouldn't be trying to handle it as a normal case.

In this situation, the `Length` check is actually *better* in one way than the inequality test I've suggested: it acts as an implicit assertion that the variable isn't null. If you have a bug and it *is* null, the test will throw an exception and the bug will be detected early. If you use the equality test it will treat null as being different to the empty string, so it will go into your "if" statement's body. If you use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` it will treat null as being the same as empty, so it won't go into the block.

Comment: I think the best thing about this is the last line.

Comment: @msarchet: It's unfortunate that I edited the answer while you were writing that comment. I assume you mean "Do you have evidence that this *is* a bottleneck?"

Comment: The post is old, but could you please give some info about the "ANSI bit"? As far as I understand the length is stored as it is before the string itself.
`unsafe void PeekLength(String s)
{
    fixed (char* st = s)
    {
        try
        {
            int* l = (int*)(st - 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Length is " + *l);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov: Assuming you mean ASCII rather than ANSI, I'd expect your PeekLength method to sometimes give the wrong answer, as there used to be a top bit set to say "This string is definitely all ASCII". I don't know whether that's still the case though.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure, I've meant ASCII =) Seems like it's not the case at least now on 4.7. PeekLength prints 2 for "青空" ("blue sky"). Is it possible to read about it somewhere and the reasoning behind?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov: That looks like a bad test case given that it's not ASCII to start with... But I can't remember where I heard about it anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeap, I mentioned only obvious not ASCII because my first runs were with "aaa" and "\0\0\0\0" strings. Ok, thanks, nevermind, I'll be keeping an eye on the info about it 'cause it sounds interesting.

Comment: @JonSkeet I accidentally stumbled upon [sync block implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/syncblk.h). For `String` it has a `BIT_SBLK_STRING_HAS_NO_HIGH_CHARS`. The length is stored at the different (also negative) offset as far as I understand.

Answer (score 11):

String.IsNullOrEmpty is the preferred method for checking for null or zero length strings.

Internally, it will use Length. The Length property for a string should not be calculated on the fly though.

If you're absolutely certain that the string will never be null and you have some strong objection to String.IsNullOrEmpty, the most efficient code I can think of would be:

```
if(s.Length > 0)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Or, possibly even better:

```
if(s != "")
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but it's overkill if the string is known not to be null.

Comment: Not only is it overkill, but it suggests you think the variable *might* be null.

Comment: then compare it with `String.Empty`

Comment: In that case `string.Length == 0` is the fastest way to determine if the string is empty.

Answer (score 5):

Accessing the `Length` property shouldn't do a count -- .NET strings store a count inside the object.

The [SSCLI/Rotor source code](http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/SourceViewer/browse.aspx?assembly=SSCLI&namespace=System&type=String) contains an interesting comment which suggests that `String.Length` is (a) efficient and (b) magic:

```
// Gets the length of this string
//
/// This is a EE implemented function so that the JIT can recognise is specially
/// and eliminate checks on character fetchs in a loop like:
/// for(int I = 0; I < str.Length; i++) str[i]
/// The actually code generated for this will be one instruction and will be inlined.
//
public extern int Length {
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    get;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the function [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)  -

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourstring))
{
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Because you had initially posted something different which didn't compile at all.  I retracted it now that you've fixed it to match what someone else posted before you.

Comment: Specifically this: if (![String.IsNullOrEmpty][1](yourstring))

Comment: that I was trying to put hyperlink.. but then realized that code block cannot. I should have seen preview. btw, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
```

true if s is null or Empty, or if s consists exclusively of white-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

As always with performace: benchmark. 
Using C# 3.5 or before, you'll want to test `yourString.Length` vs `String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)`

using C# 4, do both of the above and add `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString)`

Of course, if you know your string will never be empty, you could just attempt to access `s[0]` and handle the exception when it's not there.  That's not *normally* good practice, but it may be closer to what you need (if s should always have a non-blank value).

Comment: `IsNullOrWhitespace` will give the wrong answer though, given the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            string s = "dsfasdfsdafasd";

            timer.Start();
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
            }

            timer.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(String.Format("s.Length != 0 {0} ticks       ", timer.ElapsedTicks));

            timer.Reset();
            timer.Start();
            if (s == String.Empty)
            {
            }

            timer.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("s== String.Empty {0} ticks", timer.ElapsedTicks));
        }
```

Using the stopwatch the s.length != 0 takes less ticks then s == String.Empty

after I fix the code

Answer (score 0):

Based on your intent described in your answer, why don't you just try using this built-in option on Split:

```
s.Split(new[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `String.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and it will do it all for you.